# subdivide bezier curve in Blender 2.9

Tags: bezier-curves

I have issue subdividing bezier curve in edit mode. I go right-click and than subdivide and it does not work.

How can I add vertex in the middle (subdivide) between the already existing two on both ends of the bezier curve in Blender 2.9?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subdivide will put a division between all handles you currently have selected, so if you don't have more than one handle selected it won't do anything.  You can press <kbd>A</kbd> to highlight all handles and then run the command to subdivide the whole thing.